# Spring cloud Turbine service is not subscribed on Rabbit stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine

In my spring cloud application I want configure `turbine` service for dashboard. Example below:

```
server:
  port: 0
turbine:
  amqp:
    port: 8989

---
spring:
  profiles: docker
  rabbitmq:
    host: rabbitmq
turbine:
  clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
  appConfig: card-statement
  combineHostPort: true
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery-service:8761/eureka/

server:
  port: 8989
```

Starting `turbine` service I have no errors. Docker contained in compose is registered as `rabbitmq`. `card-statement` is a service with some `@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod =` to be observed on `dashboard`...

```
2019-05-14 16:12:57.288  INFO 6 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2019-05-14 16:12:57.373  INFO 6 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2019-05-14 16:12:57.441  INFO 6 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2019-05-14 16:12:58.494  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a0a1e3f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:12:58.617  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration$IntegrationJmxConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f59c295f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:12:58.704  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e83d22c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:12:58.961  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mbeanServer' of type [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:12:59.122  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:12:59.354  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb32660d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-14 16:13:01.701  WARN 6 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2019-05-14 16:13:01.889  INFO 6 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-14 16:13:01.889  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 15942 ms
2019-05-14 16:13:02.653  WARN 6 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-05-14 16:13:02.653  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-05-14 16:13:02.745  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@70f59913
2019-05-14 16:13:08.116  WARN 6 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-05-14 16:13:08.116  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-05-14 16:13:10.392  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-14 16:13:19.434  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-05-14 16:13:20.108  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-05-14 16:13:21.732  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel turbineStreamInput
2019-05-14 16:13:22.397  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
2019-05-14 16:13:22.608  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
2019-05-14 16:13:22.824  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
2019-05-14 16:13:23.068  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler hystrixStreamAggregator.sendToSubject.serviceActivator
2019-05-14 16:13:23.234  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2019-05-14 16:13:23.235  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'turbine-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-05-14 16:13:23.235  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2019-05-14 16:13:23.236  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:hystrixStreamAggregator.sendToSubject.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'turbineStreamInput' channel
2019-05-14 16:13:23.237  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'turbine-1.turbineStreamInput' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-05-14 16:13:23.240  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started hystrixStreamAggregator.sendToSubject.serviceActivator
2019-05-14 16:13:23.342  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2019-05-14 16:13:23.619  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2019-05-14 16:13:24.657  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-05-14 16:13:24.657  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-05-14 16:13:25.453  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-05-14 16:13:25.454  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-05-14 16:13:26.240  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2019-05-14 16:13:26.352  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
```

It seems some topics was created. Checking `rabbit` I do not see turbine service connection. Also trying to verify [`turbine.stream`](http://turbine:8989/turbine.stream) on dashboard I can see that stream is connected to dashboard, but no updates (`card-statement` service endpoints registered in `hystrix` was used). And last thing. I expected turbine is connected to `RabbitMQ`. I have not detected turbine connection to rabbit via admin console.

### Issue

Is there any ideas how to fix `turbine`?

### Turbine code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbineStream
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class TurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TurbineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```